# Iterate a Java ConcurrentSkipListMap in reverse

Tags: java, iterator, reverse, concurrentskiplistmap

I have a map with some values:

```
public ConcurrentMap<Long, Double> data = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
```

How do I iterate this in reverse?
Java iterator doesn't seem to have an next() function or a function to reverse the map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ConcurrentSkipListMap` implements `ConcurrentNavigableMap`, which has a [`descdendingMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#descendingMap--) method returning view of this map ordered in reverse:

```
Iterator<Entry<Long, Double>> reversed = data.descendingMap().entrySet().iterator();
```

However, CSLM reversed iterator is *much* slower than direct iterator (O(log N) vs O(1) for each `next()`) and thus should be used only if required rarely. Otherwise consider creating the map using "reversed" custom comparator:

```
data = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>((k1, k2) -> Long.compare(k2, k1));
```

Comment: very Clever solution! It has underlying Comparator to make reverseOrder()

Comment: @mlewandowski it has, but accepting the fact that entry and index nodes are single-linked, such iteration will be much slower because index however has to be traversed in forward direction